# How can i access stdClass Object as a string

Tags: php, stdclass

How can I access these lines like a string ?

Its a get response from twitter, and im tring to use it.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [relationship] => stdClass Object
        (
            [source] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2196933268
                    [id_str] => 2196933268
                    [screen_name] => damisleq
                    [following] => 1
                    [followed_by] => 
                    [notifications_enabled] => 
                    [can_dm] => 
                    [blocking] => 
                    [want_retweets] => 
                    [all_replies] => 
                    [marked_spam] => 
                )

            [target] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 175330071
                    [id_str] => 175330071
                    [screen_name] => sitetalkturkey
                    [following] => 
                    [followed_by] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Which lines like a string? What do you want to access in the objects?

Comment: [following] => 1  This line is i want to access

Comment: `echo $myObject->relationship->source->following;` or `echo $myObject->relationship->target->following;`

Comment: This one you suggested, turns as blank.

Comment: If my answer didn't work, improve your question

Comment: Im working on it since 2 days. Im sory for my bad english.

Im trying to echo this line [following] in to  page as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the (string) method to cast a type in to the type string. For example:

```
$x = (string) $stdVar->relationship->source->screen_name;

var_dump($x); // will output string(n) "damisleq"
```

by the way, if you get the result from Twtter as JSON you can also use associative array function in json_decode. For example. $result = json_decode($string, true); the true states you want a array as result in stead of a stdObject.

Comment: Yes output is = string(11) "damisleq"

How can i get only damisleq ?

Comment: Please learn about the different methods in PHP for outputting data: `var_dump()` can be replaced with (for example `print()`) or you could `echo` the value.... outputting text to a display really is fundamental PHP 101 day 1 type stuff